# Can one lightning event will get handled in more than two lightning component at the same time/event?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

on 1 button click I am firing one lightning event & I want to handle it in two components at a same click event, In first component it gets called/handled.
So my question is can we handle 1 lightning event in more than 1 component at a same time? or does the event will get handled in only one component at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes!

You can fire a lightning event and that will be handled in each & every component which has a handler defined in it.

Here are few considerations, for APPLICATION event, it will be handled anywhere a handler is defined but for COMPONENT events, any component with handlers in the component hierarchy will handle it, not any random component.

Questions are welcome.

Comment: see how my component hierarchy is: <Parentcmp><Childcmp1></Childcmp1><Childcmp2></Childcmp2></Parentcmp> , here I have registered event in Childcmp2 on 1 button click & handling the event in Parentcmp & Childcmp2, In Parentcmp I am able to get the data/handler is working but in ChildCmp2 handler is not working. So will the event work in this situation?

Comment: Yes, both Parentcmp & Childcmp2 will be able to handle the event if they have handlers. Please make sure the name of the handler in both the component is same as the name of the registeredEvent in Childcmp2.